# Determine if value is within uncertainty of another with modulus

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv file containing some results that show an azimuth (between 0 and 180) with some corresponding uncertainty and I'm trying to see if a known true value is within uncertainty of the result.

What I have so far is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv',header=None)
for index,row in data.iterrows():
  # Known azimuth
  true_az = row[5]

  # Test azimuth with uncertainty
  test_az = row[11]
  sigma_test_az = row[12]
```

I'm having an issue with determining if a test azimuth is within uncertainty of the true azimuth. Because it is an azimuth, I need to use a modulus of 360 to find if the true value is within uncertainty of the test. The line I have is:

```
if true_az >= np.subtract(test_az,sigma_test_az) and true_az <= (np.add(test_az, sigma_test_az) % 360):
    print("{} is within uncertainty of {} +/- {}".format(true_az, test_az, sigma_test_az))
else:
    print("{} is NOT within uncertainty of {} +/- {}".format(true_az, test_az, sigma_test_az))
```

However, this approach does not work for some test values.

For example, one line has a true_az = 30, test_az = 358, sigma_test_az = 40, but it tells me that the true value is not within uncertainty, even though it clearly is. I know the issue is with the 358 - 40 being larger than 30, but I don't know how to resolve this in the statement.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is using nested if statements where we first check if test_az + sigma_test_az >= 360. If it is, then only test if the true_az value is lower than that addition mod 360. This bypasses the check on the lower range of uncertainty but that doesn't matter since it won't be within uncertainty anyways. Here's the code.

```
 if np.add(test_az, sigma_test_az) >= 360:
    if true_az <= (np.add(test_az, sigma_test_az) % 360):
      print("{} is within uncertainty of {} +/- {}".format(true_az, test_az, sigma_test_az))
    else:
      print("{} is NOT within uncertainty of {} +/- {}".format(true_az, test_az, sigma_test_az))
  else:
    if true_az >= np.subtract(test_az,sigma_test_az) and true_az <= (np.add(test_az, sigma_test_az)):
      print("{} is within uncertainty of {} +/- {}".format(true_az, test_az, sigma_test_az))
    else:
      print("{} is NOT within uncertainty of {} +/- {}".format(true_az, test_az, sigma_test_az))
```